# Minimum hardware requirements for JIRA Software, Confluence and MySQL?

Tags: confluence, jira-agile

My company is considering a self-hosted option for a combination of JIRA, Confluence and MySQL running behind an nginx proxy. We are a very small team of 5, and expect extremely mild usage for now. I hardly even expect any concurrent usage at this point.

I am a bit puzzled by the various guidelines posted by Atlassian:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/enterprise/jira-sizing-guide-461504623.html
https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver075/jira-applications-installation-requirements-935390824.html
https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/example-size-and-hardware-specifications-from-customer-survey-76840961.html
https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/server-hardware-requirements-guide-30736403.html

It seems they don't want to bother providing actual minimum hardware requirements. For example, on the same page they could say "minimum heap size to allocate to Confluence is 1 GB and 1 GB for Synchrony (which is required for collaborative editing)" and also that " minimum hardware recommendation" is 6GB. The leap from 1 required plus 1 optional to 6 recommended minimum is bizarre, to say the least.

I think what I want to know is whether I will be able to fit this setup into a 2GB RAM machine or a 4GB RAM machine (both dual CPU).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I have done a test with following configuration:

- VM with 2 cores capped at ~2.2Ghz and 4GB RAM
- Ubuntu 16.04 server
- Docker and docker-compose
- Containers:

  - nginx
  - jwilder/docker-gen
  - jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
  - cptactionhank/atlassian-jira-software
  - cptactionhank/atlassian-confluence
  - mysql

This 4GB RAM machine is barely capable of running this setup:

```
$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3951        3553         107           0         291         157
Swap:           974         725         249
```

CPU usage was going up to 200% only during initialisation when JIRA and Confluence started with empty home dirs. The following top output is after:

- creating a space and a page in Confluence
- and a project with ~10 issues in JIRA
- and linking JIRA and Confluence together

```
$ top -o %MEM | head -15
top - 16:14:33 up  6:12,  2 users,  load average: 0.15, 0.04, 0.01
Tasks: 132 total,   1 running, 131 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  2.6 us,  0.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 95.8 id,  1.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.1 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  4046364 total,   128808 free,  3638444 used,   279112 buff/cache
KiB Swap:   998396 total,   252956 free,   745440 used.   161144 avail Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 6328 bin       20   0 3306232 1.468g      0 S   0.0 38.1  12:03.27 java
 6418 bin       20   0 2860000 1.320g      0 S   0.0 34.2  10:56.24 java
 7205 bin       20   0 2807088 476592   1724 S   0.0 11.8   1:58.37 java
 5752 999       20   0 1815480  99804   4728 S   0.0  2.5   1:11.29 mysqld
 1070 root      20   0  621908  28672   8904 S   0.0  0.7   0:30.74 dockerd
 1179 root      20   0  623004   7536   2520 S   0.0  0.2   0:16.66 docker-containe
  968 root      20   0  291352   6536   1912 S   0.0  0.2   0:00.77 snapd
 8310 root      20   0   15388   5064   3056 S   0.0  0.1   0:21.39 docker-gen
```

Confluence also allocated ~500MB RAM to Synchrony:

```
$ ps aux --sort -rss | head -4
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
bin       6328  3.3 38.3 3306232 1551120 ?     Ssl  10:14  12:12 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/atlassian/confluence...
bin       6418  2.9 34.1 2860000 1382868 ?     Ssl  10:14  10:57 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/atlassian/jira/...
bin       7205  0.5 11.7 2807088 476588 ?      Sl   10:44   1:59 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/bin/java -classpath /opt/atlassian/confluence/temp/... synchrony.core sql
```

During JIRA and Confluence install stage, MySQL peaked at around 500MB RAM usage, and during normal operation it sits around 100MB.

In my attempts, a 2GB machine was only enough to run either JIRA or Confluence without MySQL.

Conclusion:
It looks like 4GB RAM Dual core machine is the absolute minimum required for JIRA+Confluence+MySQL. But keep in mind that such a machine is barely enough for a practically empty project.

I personally was not expecting these applications to be that RAM hungry being empty.

Comment: > "I personally was not expecting these applications to be that RAM hungry being empty."   

It's java made by atlassian :D